# How do you construct a JAVA recursive method Dequeue

Tags: java, recursion

Firstly, I have a linked list implementation of a Queue where Dequeuing occurs at the **Head** of the linked list.  I have one no-argument no-return public method:

```
public void recursiveDequeue() {
  head = recursiveDequeue(size()-1, head);
}
```

And a second method:

```
private Node recursiveDequeue(int index, Node current) {
  if (current==null) {
      // some code I need to write
  }
  return current;
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this. The only thing I can change is the comment that states clearly where I need to write code.

How do you build a recursion method that dequeues from the head but whose calling method already refers to the head?  How is that even recursion?  I dont even know what this is supposed to do.

Comment: So what is this method supposed to do? Just "pop" the front node (head) off the list and return it? That doesn't seem like recursion is needed unless that `index` parameter is to specify "how many" to dequeue

Comment: If all you're doing is dequeue-ing the head why recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following. I don't know what exactly to do with *index*, seems superfluous here, but if it is the number of elements to dequeue as suggested in comments:

```
private Node recursiveDequeue(int index, Node current) {
  if (current==null || index==0) {
      return null;
  }
  return recursiveDequeue(index-1,current.next); // for a single-linked list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only code you are allowed to write is conditional upon the node argument being null then there is no solution because you can't impact a queue with a non-null head.

If the condition is intended to be `current != null` then it's possible:

```
if (current != null) {
    if (index > 0)
        return recursiveDequeue(index - 1, current.getNext());
}
return current;
```

This will dequeue `index` items. Given your no argument method calls it with `size - 1` it will dequeue all but the last item.

Comment: Happens. I do Python and Java. That's a harder switch sometimes